# ActivePivot context dependend formatting

Tags: activepivot

I have a price measure that I want to format differently in different locations, e.g. the formatting depends on the value of a dimension. I could have multiple measures with different formatting, but that would complicate a lot of other things.

The standard IFormatter framework does not have location information as far as I understand.

I guess could implement this as a post processed mesaure?
I could maybe also have different object types for the different types of prices, and then use an IFormatter implementation that switched on the object type?

Is there a best practice for this - pros/cons?

Answer (score 0):

In ActivePivot a formatter does not know the cube location for which a cell has been generated (actually with MDX constructs some cell values can be computed that are not associated to any location).

But as ActivePivot is object based there is always a solution to do what you want:

For the price measure you could write a "Price" java class that contains an amount and a currency, instead of just using a number. Out of the box ActivePivot will not know how to aggregate those prices, so you'll also write a custom aggregation function (extending *com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.aggfun.impl.GenericAggregationFunction*).

Then you can implement the *toString()* method of your Price class, as ActivePivot uses this for default formatting. And you'll have access to the currency when formatting. Of course if you want a more decoupled design, or user-based contextual formatting you can also write a PriceFormatter to format your price instances.